# Need to get all available screen resolution on single pc in c#

Tags: wpf

How we can get the list of all available scree of current computer in wpf c#. I am using following code but it not giving all resolutions.

```
 public class WpfScreen
{
    public static IEnumerable<WpfScreen> AllScreens()
    {
        foreach (Screen screen in System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens)
        {
            yield return new WpfScreen(screen);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add all screen resolutions together if you want, but the problem is defining the orientation. E.g. what if the user configured his 3 monitors in a triangle shape instead of a line? Does this affect your application's intention?

Comment: No i have only on PC and there so many screen resolutions is available.